# React Native fetch keep failing even when app is restart & connected to the internet - phone with dual sim / roaming

Tags: react-native

We were reported with issues by customers that the app keep showing error and could not recover when internet is back. There are some facts:

- They use dual sim
- They has roaming turn on all the time
- The phone is Android / Xiaomi
- **Force quit the app ... then re-open doesn't help** (other apps still can connect normal)
- **Uninstall the app and reinstall it from PlayStore ... then everything back to normal**

**React Native: 0.59.10**

We could not re-produce the issue on our end at all because none of use has dual sim + roaming. We tried to simulate lots of network condition but couldn't get the issue some of our customers have.

Any idea how we could debug this issue would be really appreciated... My thought is that ReactNative network layer failed in certain conditions and can not detect the correct communication channel with the Internet (perhaps because of the switching back  & forth of the dual sim ?), even after force quit.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: post some logs of react-native-fetch so that we can understand what is going on